# Resultado Agrupado por Campo e Listando N registros

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada área com a estrutura:

```
Id, Nome, Status
```

Tenho uma outra tabela chamada notícias com a estrutura:

```
Id,Título,Descricao,Data,IdArea,Status
```

Gostaria de retornar todos registros de noticias agrupados por código da area, onde o resultado seria agrupado pelo Id da Área, e listaria N noticias.

Formato do resultado desejado:

```
  [Id Área] 
    [idNoticia],[título],[descricao]
    [idNoticia],[título],[descricao]
    [idNoticia],[título],[descricao]
  [...]
  [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute essa query usando o driver que quiser (PDO, mysqli_* ou mysql_*):

```
SELECT idarea, id, titulo, noticia FROM noticia ORDER BY idarea;
```

Supondo que o resultado dessa query seja um array e esteja na variável `$resultado`:

```
$formatado = [];

foreach ($resultado as $linha) {
    if (!$formatado[$linha["idarea"]]) {
        $formatado[$linha["idarea"]] = [];
    }

    $formatado[$linha["idarea"]][] = $linha;
}
```

Você pode adaptar o código acima para usar com objetos ou arrays numéricos

Comment: quero ver a possibilidade do retorno ser direto o banco de dados, sem interação com php por exemplo. Ver se é viável ou não também.

Comment: Na sua pergunta não está claro a necessidade de ser formatado o resultado do banco, mas não é possível, não tem como fazer consultas que retornem arrays multidimensionais

Comment: então no caso se quiser retornar todos registros da tabela noticias para todas as áreas, no caso terei que fazer mais de uma consulta ao bd para poder receber os dados e manipula-los em php por exemplo. A idéia é agrupar todas as notícias por área, dai dava para manipular os dados melhor.

Comment: Acho que não entendi, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: valeu, deu para entender sua resposta, é que queria varrer a tabela Area, e retornar agrupado por Id da area todas as noticias correspondentes, mas queria em um array multidimencional para não precisar fazer n consultas no banco e retornar separadamente para cada IdArea

Comment: Em geral você dificilmente vai precisar realizar mais de uma consulta para mostrar os dados, mas talvez seja necessário formatar, como nesse caso. Uma observação, esse tipo de formatação é preferível fazer no frontend, para aliviar o servidor